# Find the Galois Group of $(x^3+x^2+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't know how to begin to find this particular Galois group since I do not know the splitting field. Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: Whenever I say "the whole polynomial," I mean $(x^3+x^2+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)$.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3+x^2+1$. We then have:

$$x^3+x^2+1=(x-\alpha)(x^2+(\alpha+1)x+\alpha^2+\alpha)$$

Now, we know that:

$$\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1=0\rightarrow \alpha^3=\alpha^2+1$$
$$\alpha^4=\alpha^3+\alpha=\alpha^2+\alpha+1$$
$$\alpha^6=(\alpha^3)^2=(\alpha^2+1)^2=\alpha^4+1=\alpha^2+\alpha$$

Using this info, let's guess and check values of $x$ to find more zeroes. Eventually, we find $x=\alpha^2$:

$$x^2+(\alpha+1)x+\alpha^2+\alpha=(x-\alpha^2)(x-(\alpha^2+\alpha+1))$$

Thus, it took a single field extension of order $3$ to split $x^3+x^2+1$ into linear factors, so the Galois group of this splitting field is $C_3$.

Now, conveniently for us, this splitting field also splits the polynomial $x^3+x+1$. To verify this, again, using guess and check, we find $x=\alpha^2+1$ is a root:

$$x^3+x+1=(x-(\alpha^2+1))(x^2+(\alpha^2+1)x+\alpha^2+\alpha+1)$$

Then, again using guess and check, we can factor that last quadratic by plugging in $x=\alpha+1$:

$$x^2+(\alpha^2+1)x+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=(x-(\alpha+1))(x-(\alpha^2+\alpha))$$

Since the splitting field of $x^3+x^2+1$ also splits $x^3+x+1$, this means it took a single field extension of order $3$ to split both of these cubic polynomials. Thus, do not make the mistake of multiplying in two copies of $C_3$ into the Galois group of the only polynomial since we only made one field extension to split both cubics.

Now, let $\beta$ be a root of $x^2+x+1$. We then have:

$$x^2+x+1=(x-\beta)(x+\beta+1)$$

Thus, it took a single field extension of order $2$ to split $x^2+x+1$ into linear factors, so the Galois group of this splitting field is $C_2$.

Now, to recap, the splitting field of the whole polynomial is $\Bbb{F}_3(\alpha)(\beta)$, where $\alpha$ has irreducible polynomial $x^3+x^2+1$ and $\beta$ has irreducible polynomial $x^2+x+1$. Therefore, any automorphism of this splitting field will contain a 3-cycle between the roots of $x^3+x^2+1$ and a 2-cycle between the roots of $x^2+x+1$, so the Galois group of the splitting field is $C_3 \times C_2$.

Comment: But what's the rigorous theorem that tells you that the Galois group of the full polynomial is the direct product?

Comment: @KennyWong I'm not sure if it's a theorem with an explicit name, but it's just kind of common sense. The Galois group is the permutation of the roots. Here, we can permute $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$, and $\alpha^2+\alpha+1$ in a 3-cycle since they are all roots to the same polynomial and we can permute $\beta$ and $\beta+1$ in a 2-cycle since they are all roots to the same polynomial. Since we can permute some of the roots in a 3-cycle and some of the roots in a 2-cycle, we get the Galois group of all the possible permutations of the roots to be a direct product of $C_3$ and $C_2$.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. (I think you intended to write "roots to the same _irreducible polynomial_", by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a finite field, you only need to find a degree of splitting field over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$. We will show that the degree is 6 so that the splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_{2^{6}}$ and the Galois group is $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

In general, any degree $d$ irreducible polynomial over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ splits completely in $\mathbb{F}_{q^{m}}$, since the splitting field of the polynomial is $\mathbb{F}_{q^{d}}$, and it can be embedded into $\mathbb{F}_{q^{m}}$ since $d|m$. Hence our polynomial splits completely in $\mathbb{F}_{2^{6}}$, so the splitting field sits inside $\mathbb{F}_{2^{6}}$.

By the way, any other proper subfields of $\mathbb{F}^{2^{6}}$ can't be a splitting field. For example, we have 2 candidates: $\mathbb{F}_{2^{2}}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{2^{3}}$. In $\mathbb{F}_{2^{2}}$, $x^{3} + x^{2} + 1$ doesn't split completely so it is impossible. Similarly, $x^{2} + x + 1$ doesn't split completely in $\mathbb{F}_{2^{3}}$, so the only possibility is $\mathbb{F}_{2^{6}}$.

Using this argument, you may show the following: splitting field of the polynomial $f(x) = p_{1}(x)\cdots p_{r}(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ where all $p_{i}(x)$'s are irreducible and $\deg p_{i} = d_{i}$ is $\mathbb{F}_{q^{d}}$, where $d = \mathrm{lcm}\{d_{1}, \dots, d_{r}\}$.